# Identifying top and bottom 1% of raster cells to identify threshold value for symbology using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

My question is similar to [Identifying top 10% of raster cells using ArcGIS Desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183193).

I have a Raster layer and want to identify the threshold value for top 1% and bottom 1% of the raster.  This is so I can change the symbology to show top 1% as one colour, and Bottom 1% as another.

The raster is a 32bit floating point file with a Max value of 2630.755126953125 and a Min value of -2737.8447265625

I am using ArcMap 10.61 Desktop

I have tried to use the formula indicated in the response below with no success.  I tried to test it with the 10% value (0.9) before trying it with 1% (0.99).  I end up with a blank raster.

> radouxju answered Mar 3 '16 at 6:40
>
> From your comment I understand
> that you are not looking for percentile but a given percentage of your
> range. You can use the raster calculator
>
> Con("raster" >= (0.9 * ("raster".maximum - "raster".minimum) +
> "raster".minimum), 1) of course 0.9 could be replaced by any value
> (this is an example with 10%). Note that the results will be a raster
> with 1 or Nodata, but you can also set a value instead of NoData if
> you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python and [numpy.percentile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html):

```py
import arcpy
import numpy as np

rasterfile = r'C:\GIS\data\DEM50m\grid50m\nh_65_3.tif' #Change
arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(rasterfile) #Create array from raster
arr[arr==-9999]=np.nan #I have nodata values of -9999. This converts them to nan...

for p in [1,99]:
    print np.nanpercentile(arr, p) # ...so i can use nanpercentile to ignore them
    #print np.percentile(arr,p) #If you have no nan use np.percentile
```

[image]